# Diferencia de fechas con varios filtros

Tags: powerbi

Mi duda es algo compleja y espero obtener respuesta pronto, gracias de antemano.

Tengo un informe el cual está compuesto principalmente de cajas.

Esas cajas tienen distintas fases, en concreto 6, de las cuales estoy intentando obtener el tiempo que ha tardado la caja en estar en cada una.

Mi problema viene cuando aplico dos segmentaciones de datos sobre la tarjeta, una de ellas para seleccionar el ID de la caja que quiero en concreto, y la otra para filtrar la fase de la que quiero saber el tiempo.

El código utilizado en la medida para calcular esa diferencia es el siguiente:

```
TIME_FASE_CAJA = SUMX('ecrimesapro snc_fasecaja';
DATEDIFF('ecrimesapro snc_fasecaja'[HORA_ENTRADA_FASE].[Date];
'ecrimesapro snc_fasecaja'[HORA_SALIDA_FASE].[Date];HOUR))
```

Adjunto unas imágenes de las medidas utilizadas en el proceso y espero que alguien encuentre el fallo.
Muchas gracias.

[image: Captura del informe]

---

Comment: Recalco una cosa, estoy usando el sumx para obtener el tiempo total de todas las fases de la caja, pero al filtrar por fase, estas me aparecen a 0 menos una que hace la suma de todas y se queda con el valor es decir al comprobar resultados sale: FASE 1: 0 FASE 2 : 0 FASE 3: 0 FASE 4: 0 FASE 5: 24 FASE 6: 0 , todas las horas de las fases se me agrupan en una sola.

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de enterder tu problema, pero intuyo que el resultado no es el esperado dependiendo de algún filtro aplicado.

Para salvar esto, tienes las funciones que te permiten obviar dichos filtros y ajustar el contexto en el que trabaja la media. Por ejemplo ALL(), ALLSELECTED().

Si lo que quieres es que un filtro no aplique a tu medida deberás hacer algo como

```
TIME_FASE_CAJA = CALCULATE(
    TIME_FASE_CAJA = SUMX('ecrimesapro snc_fasecaja';
    DATEDIFF('ecrimesapro snc_fasecaja'[HORA_ENTRADA_FASE].[Date];
    'ecrimesapro snc_fasecaja'[HORA_SALIDA_FASE].[Date];HOUR))
  ;ALL(NombreTabla)
)
```

Donde `NombreTabla` es la tabla cuyos filtros aplicados quieres evitar.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuando filtro por una caja y por una fase se me calcule mediante esa medida el tiempo que ha tardado la caja en pasar por dicha fase pero los valores que me salen como resultado no son correctos y nose si el fallo está en que aplico dos segmentaciones de datos a la vez aunque sean valores distintos quizás esté produciendo eso el fallo.Gracias por tu respuesta y si necesitas algo más para resolver mi duda pidemelo.